# Unable to provision with file multiple time

Tags: linux, terraform, openssh

While trying to provision with file multiple times, second occurance is not being considered. Not sure if I'm doing it correctly.

Please throw some light !

The below block works perfectly -

```
source      = "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/aws_migration_using_terraform/tcs-btag-account_us-east-2/aws_infra_automation" 

destination = "/home/ubuntu"
}
```

However, this one didn't work and there is no error thrown by terraform itself !

```
    source      = "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/aws_migration_using_terraform/tcs-btag-account_us-east-2/livedevops" 

    destination = "/home/ubuntu"

  }
```

The entire code is given below --

```
resource "tls_private_key" "bastion-key" {

  algorithm = "RSA"

  rsa_bits  = 4096

}



resource "aws_key_pair" "generated_key" {

  key_name   = var.bastion_key

  public_key = tls_private_key.bastion-key.public_key_openssh

}



resource "aws_instance" "bastion_host_us-east-2a" {

  ami                         = var.bastion_ami_id

  instance_type               = var.bastion_ec2_instance_type

  disable_api_termination     = false

  subnet_id                   = aws_subnet.devops_mig_pub_sub_01.id

  vpc_security_group_ids      = [aws_security_group.sg-btag-allow.id, aws_security_group.sg-ssh-allow.id]

  associate_public_ip_address = true

  availability_zone           = aws_subnet.devops_mig_pub_sub_01.availability_zone

  key_name                    = aws_key_pair.generated_key.id





  connection {

    type        = "ssh"

    host        = self.public_ip

    user        = "ubuntu"

    port        = 22

    private_key = tls_private_key.bastion-key.private_key_pem

    timeout     = "60s"

  }

#Copying files from local to remote

  provisioner "file" {

    source      = "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/aws_migration_using_terraform/tcs-btag-account_us-east-2/aws_infra_automation" 

    destination = "/home/ubuntu"

  }

  provisioner "file" {

    source      = "/home/ubuntu/Desktop/aws_migration_using_terraform/tcs-btag-account_us-east-2/livedevops" 

    destination = "/home/ubuntu"

  }

  user_data = <<-EOF

    #!/bin/bash

    sudo apt update -y

    sudo apt install -y software-properties-common 

    sudo add-apt-repository --yes --update ppa:ansible/ansible

    sudo apt update -y

    sudo apt install -y ansible

    /usr/bin/ansible --version > ansible-v.txt

     echo "Installing the cloudwatch agent for Ubuntu Linux."

        curl -O https://s3.amazonaws.com/amazoncloudwatch-agent/ubuntu/amd64/latest/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.deb

        dpkg -i -E ./amazon-cloudwatch-agent.deb

    EOF  

  tags = {

    "Name" = "bastion_host"

  }

}







output "private_key" {

  value     = tls_private_key.bastion-key.private_key_pem

  sensitive = true

}

output "bastion_public_ip" {

  value = aws_instance.bastion_host_us-east-2a.public_ip

}

output "bastion_private_ip" {

  value = aws_instance.bastion_host_us-east-2a.private_ip

}

resource "aws_ebs_volume" "bastion_storage" {

  availability_zone = var.bastion-ebs-availability-zone

  size              = 50

  type              = "gp2"

  tags = {

    "Name" = "bastion_ebs_volume"

  }

}





resource "local_file" "bastion_private_key" {

  content         = tls_private_key.bastion-key.private_key_pem

  filename        = "bastion-key.pem"

  file_permission = "0400"

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see `ubuntu` being the user used to SSH to target machine. It's a bad idea to copy files directly to `HOME` directory of the user & in this case the `file` provisioner is just replacing everything available on `/home/ubuntu` directory.

The above directory also contains your SSH public keys used for authentication in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. That's the reason it's failing at the second file provisioner.

You create a `tmp` directory under `/home/ubuntu` or use `/tmp` or `/var/tmp` directories if they allow `ubuntu` user to write something to write.

Comment: You create a tmp directory under `/home/ubuntu` or use `/tmp` or `/var/tmp` directories if they allow ubuntu user to write something to write. ...

I tried this method, not able to transfer the second drirectory